# displaying data from database with new line to jtable row netbeans

Tags: java, database, swing, netbeans, jtable

can someone help me? i have been trying to show my data from database with new lines to jtable row but it doesnt show with a new line, the text are sticked together

```
    String prodname = prodbox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String qty = txtqty.getText();
    String prod = prodID.getSelectedItem().toString();

    int quantity = Integer.valueOf(txtqty.getText().trim());

//         VectorTableCellRenderer renderer = new VectorTableCellRenderer();

//set TableCellRenderer into a specified JTable column class
//    jTable6.setDefaultRenderer(Vector.class, renderer);


    String sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE "
            + " productID = ('"+prod+"')";

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(i == 0 && !prodname.equals("") ){
            arr[i] = prodname;
            ctr++;
        }
        else
            break;


    }

    for(int i = 0; i < qty_arr.length; i++){
        if(i == 0 && !qty.equals("") || i == 0 && !qty.equals("0")){
            qty_arr[i] = qty;
            totalqty += quantity;

        }
        else
            break;

    }


    for(int i = 0; i < ctr; i++){
        checker++;
        if(checker > 0){
            allQuantity.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        allQuantity.append(qty_arr[i]);
        //comma2 = "\n ";


        }





    for(int i = 0; i < ctr; i++){
        if(checker > 0){
            allProducts.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        allProducts.append(arr[i]);
        //comma = "\n ";

    }
```

i tried append, with a line separator and with a "\n" but 
this still shows

result of my table:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5dAY3MT.jpg]

Comment: There is no database code or JTable code in you posting. I have no idea what you are trying to do since your question is about displaying data from a database to a JTable. If you want multiple rows of data, then use the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` to add separate rows of data.

Comment: jTable6.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
this is the code for displaying data, *mysql
but i cant display a new line in the talberow

Comment: i want to display multiple lines of text in 1 row, not with multiple rows

Comment: Set a default cell renderer  to your jTable6 @ Ariel